# Endogeneity in Discrete Choice Models

Tags: logistic, causality, endogeneity, choice-modeling

Suppose we are trying to estimate a model to predict failure of a company as a function of some firm-level and macroeconomic variables using a logistic regression

$Y_{it} =  X_{it} \beta + \epsilon_{it}$

where $Y_{it} = \lbrace 0,\,1\rbrace$ is the indicator variable with $Y_{it}=1$ meaning the firm is bankrupt and $X_{it}$ is a set of explanatory variables measured with say, a quarter/month lag. Furthermore, suppose firm leverage $L_{i,\,t-1}$ is one of the $X's$.

I'm interested in the following case. Suppose, creditors of a firm take into account the probability of bankruptcy at a point in time to decide how much money to lend, i.e, $L_{i,\,t-1}$ is a function of $P(Y_{it}=1\,|\,X_{it})$. Thus, there is "endogeneity" in the estimation. How is estimation affected if the problem is ignored? If this is indeed a problem, how should we account for it?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the main issue is one of causality: do you think $L_{i,t-1}$ causally affects any of the other $X$'s?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Let's say it doesn't. But if beliefs about default influence leverage, it should be accounted for to estimate the impact of leverage on default.

Comment: Correct. But if $L_{i,t-1}$ is not causally related to any other $X$'s, then there is no backdoor path creating a confounding variable. Simply including $L_{i,t-1}$ in your regression (which I'm assuming you're doing) should be sufficient, and there shouldn't be any confounding bias present in your result. Now if some of the other $X$'s are causally related, then you should prepare a careful causal diagram and see if you have any backdoor paths that need stopping up.

Comment: But isn't there a reverse causality here?

Comment: It's a bi-directional causality. While the loan officers are evaluating their perceived $P(Y_{it}=1|X_{it})$ to decide how much to lend $L_{i,t-1},$ presumably the amount that actually is lent would, in turn, affect whether $Y_{it}=1,$ right? So in a causal diagram, you'd have $L_{i,t-1}\leftrightarrow Y_{it}.$ That's not a problem for linear regression unless $L_{i,t-1}$ is causally related to other $X$'s, which you've said is not the case. Keep in mind that linear regression cannot distinguish between $X\to Y$ and $Y\to X.$ You need expert opinion to decide that.

Comment: I see where my confusion lies. Perhaps I should have phrased the question better. I'm  not interested in the causal effect of leverage on probability to default. Rather, I'm more worried about bias and consistency of the estimates. My end goal is to use the estimated model to predict default out of sample.

Comment: But causality IS the answer to your question. These sorts of biases (missing variable bias, confounding bias, endogeneity, and several other biases) are much more intuitively examined through the lens of the new causal revolution. For example: before the new causal revolution, what was the definition of a confounding variable? You would get more definitions for that than there are statisticians. With the new causal revolution, you have an unambiguous, helpful definition that's easy to understand: a confounder is a variable that sets up a backdoor path.